# Find the Number of Integral Solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ be an integer such that $1 \leq k \leq \left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)$ for some odd prime $p$. Let $ a$ be another integer such that $1 \leq a \leq (p-1)$. Then find the number of integral values of $k$ that satisfy,
$$\left(\dfrac{ka}{p}\right)-\left\lfloor\dfrac{ka}{p}\right\rfloor<\dfrac{1}{2}$$

It is easy to show that the number of solutions is greater than or equal to $\left\lfloor\dfrac{p}{2a}\right\rfloor$ but I have a feeling that the number equals $\left\lfloor\dfrac{p}{2a}\right\rfloor$. But I can't prove it. Any help will be appreciated.

**My Try**

> Instead of trying to find out the number of integral solutions of the inequality, I considered finding out the number of integral solutions of the following inequality, which is- $$\left(\dfrac{ka}{p}\right)-\left\lfloor\dfrac{ka}{p}\right\rfloor>\dfrac{1}{2}$$ Now notice that since $\left\lfloor xy \right\rfloor \geq  \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor .\left\lfloor y \right\rfloor$ therefore,
>   $$\left(\dfrac{ka}{p}\right)-\left\lfloor\dfrac{ka}{p}\right\rfloor>\dfrac{1}{2} \implies \left(\dfrac{ka}{p}\right)-k\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{p}\right\rfloor>\dfrac{1}{2} \implies k>\dfrac{1}{2 \left ( {\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)-\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{p}\right\rfloor} \right )}$$ But I can't show that every $k$ satisfying this bound will satisfy the given inequality. Notice that since $\left \lfloor \dfrac{a}{p} \right \rfloor=0$, the given bound on $k$ simplifies to $\left \lceil \dfrac{p}{2a} \right \rceil  \leq k \leq \left (\dfrac{p-1}{2} \right )$.
>   That's where I am stuck.

One more remark is necessary. If it can be shown that there exists no common solution to the inequality $\left \lceil \dfrac{p}{2a} \right \rceil \leq k \leq \left \lfloor \dfrac{p}{2a}+\dfrac{p}{a}\left\lfloor\dfrac{ka}{p}\right\rfloor\right \rfloor$ then the exact number of solution of the given inequaity can be determined.

Comment: is `[..]`, the flooe function?

Comment: Yes, it's the Greatest Integer Function.